# Frame number in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have the following in my document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usetheme{Goettingen}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}


\frame{
\frametitle{test}
test
}
\end{document}
```

How can I make these frame numbers bigger?

Answer (score 32):

You can set the `page number in head/foot` font; a little example using `size=\large`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{test}
test
}
\end{document}
```

[image]