# How to remove slide/frame counter on first page?

Tags: beamer, counters

I tried to implement something like [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74241/frame-number-in-beamer) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82794/removing-page-number-from-title-frame-without-changing-the-theme). However, it does not work. Problem is that on the first page the slide counter appears. And I do not want this.

So how can I get rid of the slide counter on the first titlepage?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{german}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\Large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\large}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[My study]{Test text\\ Text Text Text TextvTextTextTextTextText Text Text}   
\author[J. Doe]{\textbf{My name\\ \vspace{0.2cm}Test test \\Test test TEst Test Test TeTs}} 
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{myLogo}}
\date{Place, 11 March 2020}
\titlepage




\section{Introduction}
\frame[label=Einf]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{details}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\section{Test2}
\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
Test
}



\section[Sources]{references}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test \& Test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Beamerpaket]{paket} \emph{Beamer Paket} \\ 
\text{http://latex-beamer.sourceforge.net/}

\end{thebibliography}


\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach proposed in the questions you posted was correct.
Specifically

```
{
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=date in head/foot.bg}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
```

contained what you were looking for.
The copy paste of `\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=date in head/foot.bg}` obviously does not work, because you are usigng a different theme (`Goettingen` instead of `Madrid`).

Therefore, you need to change `page number in head/foot` with the color defined in you theme, [which is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246334/177) `structure.fg!10`.

So you obtain:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{german}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\Large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\large}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[My study]{Test text\\ Text Text Text TextvTextTextTextTextText Text Text}
\author[J. Doe]{\textbf{My name\\ \vspace{0.2cm}Test test \\Test test TEst Test Test TeTs}}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{myLogo}}
\date{Place, 11 March 2020}

{
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!10}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}


\section{Introduction}
\frame[label=Einf]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{details}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\section{Test2}
\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
Test
}



\section[Sources]{references}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test \& Test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Beamerpaket]{paket} \emph{Beamer Paket} \\
\text{http://latex-beamer.sourceforge.net/}

\end{thebibliography}


\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image]
To conclude, I suggest you to post actual MWEs. In this case we do not have the `myLogo` file.

Comment: Thanks for the posts, works so fine and I will accept it. However, I have one more problem: I have some slides at the end which I do not want to count and where the slide number should not appear. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: try `\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain] stuff \end{frame}`

Comment: @StatTistician otherwise encolse those frames within `{ \setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!10}` ... `}` like so:
 `{ \setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!10} \begin{frame} [noframenumbering] frame at the end \end{frame}  \begin{frame} [noframenumbering] other  frame \end{frame} }`

Comment: @StatTistician however, please avoid adding additional questions in the comments. If you have other issues/question, open a new and different question; this is not a forum site.
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I opened a new question, since I did not get it working with your solution here. Maybe you could help here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531333/slides-at-the-end-not-to-be-counted-and-no-counter-to-be-shown