# Slides at the end not to be counted and no counter to be shown (depending on frame type)

Tags: beamer, counters

I have some slides at the end of my presentation (appendix) which I do not want to be counted and where the slide number should not appear.

Furthermore I use

```latex
\frame[label=details]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{Test}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
stuff here
}
```

quite often, so not `latex\begin{frame} and \end{frame}`

My MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}


\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\Large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\large}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]



\newenvironment{specialframe}
{
    \begingroup
    \advance\textwidth2cm % see beamerthemeGoettingen.sty for the number
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \begin{frame}[plain]
}
{
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\title[My study]{Test text\\ Text Text Text TextvTextTextTextTextText Text Text}
\author[J. Doe]{\textbf{My name\\ \vspace{0.2cm}Test test \\Test test TEst Test Test TeTs}}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{myLogo}}
\date{Place, 11 March 2020}

{
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!10}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}


\section{Introduction}
\frame[label=Einf]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{details}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\section{Test2}
\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
Test
}


\begin{specialframe}{Test}
    here no navigation pane
\end{specialframe}

\section{End}
\frame[label=End]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{details}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\section[Sources]{references}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test \& Test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Beamerpaket]{paket} \emph{Beamer Paket} \\
\text{http://latex-beamer.sourceforge.net/}

\end{thebibliography}


\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Update2: Last three slides should not be counted and furthermore no frame count number should appear, however the table of contents in the navigation pane on the right side should not be split/changed:

[image: s]

The third slide is a special environment (Test here no navigation pane) where I do not want to have a navigation pane (this slide should also not be counted and no frame count to be shown). So here in this specific example the count would be 1/2 and 2/2.

[image: hsot]
While trying to implement a suggestion in the comments from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531295/how-to-remove-slide-frame-counter-on-first-page) it did not work. When I try to add [noframenumbering,plain] to begin frame then everything disappears inlcuding my navigation on the right side. When I just add [noframenumbering] without plain it does not remove the counter.

My problem is besides this furthermore connected to the fact that I use two different types of frames. 
`latex\begin{frame} Text \end{frame}`
and

```latex
\frame[label=details]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{Test}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
stuff here
}
```

(I also wondered which one is "better" or should I avoid using one type?)

I need a solution for both in order to avoid for such a frame to be counted and that a frame counter is shown. How can I avoid that a frame at the end is counted and that a frame count is shown?

Update:

In my case those frames I do not want to be counted and where the frame counter should not be shown on the slide (but I still want my navigation pane at the right side) are at the end of my presentation. So a solution which assumes this would work for me. However, it is actually a good thing to also have an implementation for this problem in case there is a slide in the middle of the presentation.

Comment: Please clarify if my understanding is correct: assuming that you have `n` slides, and that you want to "hide" the page count in the last `k` slide, at page `1<i<k` should be `i/n-k`, am I correct?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin Yes, so when I have 10 slides, first one is the title page (not be counted and no frame number shown) and the last 2 slides are bibliography or appendix, I do not want these 2 slides to be counted and on these last 2 slides there should be no fram number. However, you can also make it easier (if that is easer) and implement a function which I can put around a frame to get this frame out of the counter and that no frame count is shown. Would be useful, in case a fram in the middle of the presentation should not be counted and no fram counter shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a handy package `appendixnumberbeamer` which fixes the page counting problem: it simply resets the counter to 0 when the `\appendix` command is issued. Then you can use the same technique you used in your title slide to hide the page numbering.  Since the original `\appendix` command in Beamer separates the slides completely from the rest of the slides (which you don't want), we can remove that part of the definition to have your uncounted slides in the contents lists throughout.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\pretocmd{\appendix}{\let\appendixorig\relax}{}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{german}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\Large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\large}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\newenvironment{specialframe}
{\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
    \begingroup
    \advance\textwidth2cm % see beamerthemeGoettingen.sty for the number
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \begin{frame}[plain]
}
{
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title[My study]{Test text\\ Text Text Text TextvTextTextTextTextText Text Text}
\author[J. Doe]{\textbf{My name\\ \vspace{0.2cm}Test test \\Test test TEst Test Test TeTs}}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\date{Place, 11 March 2020}

{
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!10}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}


\section{Introduction}
\frame[label=Einf]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{details}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{specialframe}
\frametitle{A special frame}
Some stuff
\end{specialframe}


\appendix
\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=structure.fg!10}
\section{End}

\frame[label=End]{
\frametitle{Test \hyperlink{details}{\beamergotobutton{Test}}}
\vspace{0.05cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
}


\section[Sources]{references}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Test \& Test}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Beamerpaket]{paket} \emph{Beamer Paket} \\
\text{http://latex-beamer.sourceforge.net/}

\end{thebibliography}


\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]